# implementing conditional statements in string form python

Tags: python

I have a string which has some conditional statement. For example

```
a = 5
b = "a != 0"
```

I want to enforce b but the condition is given in a string form. Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: This is something you can achieve by using `eval(b)`. Do you need to achieve this without `eval`?

Comment: You can use `if eval(b):`

Comment: This is a pretty strong code smell and almost certainly an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you need to do this?